# How to vertically fit contents into for different screen sizes? Code below

Tags: html, css

I have tried everything from html and body with adjusting height, min-height, max-height set to 100%vh or 100% or js to check screen size but nothing works. Finally created a container to set height but even container goes out of screen size vertically. All buttons needs to adjust to screen size but lower ones are getting cut off.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: none;
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  overflow: auto;
}

.button {
  background-color: #e7e7e7;
  position: absolute;
  border: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 2vw 3vw;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 4vw;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.button1 {
  margin-left: 50%;
  margin-top: 45%;
}

.button2 {
  margin-left: 30%;
  margin-top: 65%;
}

.button3 {
  margin-left: 80%;
  margin-top: 50%;
}

.button4 {
  margin-left: 80%;
  margin-top: 10%;
}

.button5 {
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-top: 10%;
}

.button6 {
  margin-left: 40%;
  margin-top: 20%;
}

button7 {
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-top: 45%;
}

.button8 {
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-top: 90%;
}

.button9 {
  margin-left: 70%;
  margin-top: 75%;
}

.button10 {
  margin-left: 50%;
  margin-top: 95%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px),
(min-height: 100%) {
  .button {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-size: 5vw
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <button class="button button1" value="1">1</button>
    <button class="button button2" value="2">2</button>
    <button class="button button3" value="3">3</button>
    <button class="button button4" value="4">4</button>
    <button class="button button5" value="5">5</button>
    <button class="button button6" value="6">6</button>
    <button class="button button7" value="7">7</button>
    <button class="button button8" value="8">8</button>
    <button class="button button9" value="9">9</button>
    <button class="button button10" value="10">10</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: For the future, not every line needs to be indented with **`** in your snippet, only the opening, and close.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: vh instead of % in each button's margin-top

```
.button1 {margin-left: 60vw; margin-top: 35vh;}
```